# how to check if a matrix has the same value in a row or column in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have a homework problem. It requires us to make a matrix based on user's input. For example : if user input 4 so the matrix will be 4 X 4. After that, the program will check if the matrix has the same value in a row or column. and it will give yes or no output.

For example :

input :

```
2
1 2
2 1
```

Output :

```
Yes
```

(because that matrix doesnt has a same value in a row or a column.)

Input 2 :

```
3
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 3 3
```

Output :

```
No
```

(Because that matrix have same values in a row or column (3 & 3 and 7 & 7)

Input 3:

```
2
1 2
3 2
```

Output :

```
No
```

(because that matrix have same value on column 1.)

Input 4

```
2
1 1
3 4
```

Output :

```
No
```

(because that matrix has same value in first row(1 1)

I have tried to do that, but some 'cases' still doesnt work. For example, i tried to include a count in my code but some of the count is not true.

example :
input :

```
4
3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5
6 5 6 3
5 4 6 3
```

OUTPUT :

```
No
count : 2
```

(it supposed to be 3 because it has the same value which are 6 (on row 3), 6 on column 3, and 3 on column 4.)

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{

    int matrix[500][500];
    int testcase;
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&testcase); getchar();

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < testcase; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]); getchar();
        }
    }
    // printf("[0,0] = %c",matrix[0][0]);
    // printf("\n[0,1] = %c",matrix[0][1]);
    // printf("\n[1,0] = %c",matrix[1][0]);
    // printf("\n[1,1] = %c",matrix[1][1]);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < testcase; j++) {
            if(matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+1]) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            else if(matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]) {
                count = count + 1;
            }

        }
    }
    if(count > 0) {
        printf("No\n");
    } else{
        printf("Yes\n");
    }

    printf("Count : %d\n",count );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your testing will go out of bounds of the initialized parts of the arrays.

Comment: There should be two sets of test loops: one to examine each row, and one to examine each column. Aside: you can remove every `getchar()` because `scanf` will filter the whitespace (in this usage).

Answer (score 0):

As I see you check if 2 numbers of the same value differ only one column or one row here:

```c
if(matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+1]) {
      count = count + 1;
}
else if(matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]) {
      count = count + 1;
}
```

I think that you might need a temp variable so that you can scan each line and then each column separately , for example:

```c
temp = matrix[i][j];
if(checkRow(temp, i, j, matrix, testcase) == true) count++;
if(checkColumn(temp, i, j, matrix, testcase) == true) count++;
```

and the checkRow would be something like this:

```c
bool checkRow(int temp, int row, int col, int matrix[][500], int size)
{
   for(int i=col; i < size;)
   {
      if(temp == matrix[row][i]) return true;
   }

    return false;
}
```

and respectively you will build the checkColumn function.

**EDIT**:
Since you told me you haven't learned how to use functions yet, this would be your final program. It works and I might suggest that the final test case should output "count = 4" since there is a case that you might missed.
Here is the code:

```c
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{

    int matrix[500][500];
    int testcase;
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&testcase); getchar();
    int temp;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < testcase; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]); getchar();
        }
    }
    // printf("[0,0] = %c",matrix[0][0]);
    // printf("\n[0,1] = %c",matrix[0][1]);
    // printf("\n[1,0] = %c",matrix[1][0]);
    // printf("\n[1,1] = %c",matrix[1][1]);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < testcase; j++) {
            temp = matrix[i][j];
            //Scan current row
            for(unsigned k = j+1; k < testcase; k++)
            {
                if(temp == matrix[i][k])
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Scan current column
            for(unsigned k = i+1; k < testcase; k++)
            {
                if(temp == matrix[k][j])
                {
                    count ++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(count > 0) {
        printf("No\n");
    } else{
        printf("Yes\n");
    }

    printf("Count : %d\n",count );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

May I suggest that before you copy the code you must understand the algorithm that lies behind it. It's simple and brute force thinking.

Comment: The problem with passing a 2-star argument is that is not a 2D array, and the compiler can't tell what its dimensions are. You would use the two stars for an array of pointers.

Comment: Sure, You have to make a loop that scans the line and the column that each "matrix[i][j]" element belongs to. if you find a duplicate increase count. Be aware that you must start scanning from the current i or j when you scan your column or row respectively I hope I helped. I will provide a more complete answer later on if you struggle to understand what I suggested. Good luck!